# Activerecord relation touch: true doesn't update updated_at attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got some issue with caching. 
I cannot expire the cache because "touch: true" in my association doesn't work.

```
class Teaser < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :content, inverse_of: :teaser, optional: true, touch: true
end
```

If I update the content instance  the `Teaser` updated_at attribute doesn't change.

I try to add a callback on save and now it works...

Why?

Comment: touch will update the belongs_to association's updated_at not `Teaser`

Comment: Please show your `content.rb`

Comment: @Cyzanfar so how can I expire the cache?

Comment: Here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching it will explain it better than I do